# Observer not assigned on create

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am doing this in code in order to handle multiple views from multiple components

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cy8jza?file=src/app/app.service.ts (check the console for the error)

```
export class ViewGroup {
    _onViewChanged: any;
    OnViewChanged$ : Observable<any>;
    _onViewAdded: any;
    OnViewAdded$ : Observable<any>;
    _onViewRemoved: any;
    OnViewRemoved$ : Observable<any>;

    viewsSet = new Set<string>();
    currentView = "";
    previousView = "";

    constructor(){
    this.OnViewChanged$ = Observable.create(obs => this._onViewChanged = obs);
    this.OnViewAdded$ = Observable.create(obs => this._onViewAdded = obs);
    this.OnViewRemoved$ = Observable.create(obs => this._onViewRemoved = obs);
}
}
```

somnwhere in the code I do

```
this._availableView.set(name,  new ViewGroup());
```

and then call

```
this._availableView.get(group)._onViewAdded.next(view);
```

but I can't call the next on it, it s say undefined.

It's exactly the same procedure has

```
this.onGroupAdded$ = Observable.create(e => this._onGroupAdded = e)
```

but this one work in stackblitz